# Is there any way to add CA certificate in the android phone? (not under the user but under the system)

Tags: android, performance-testing

To perform Mobile performance testing, the root CA certificate needs to be installed in the android phone under system, but unable to do that, the certificates can only be installed under user.
Due to this web applications can be tested in mobile, to perform testing on native or hybrid apps the certificate needs to be installed in system.

I went through the below blog, but was unable to follow those steps due to complexity
https://medium.com/hackers-secrets/adding-a-certificate-to-android-system-trust-store-ae8ca3519a85

can anyone help by providing steps to do the same?